# How to prove the best constant in “Hardy-Littlewood-Polya inequality” book?

Tags: inequality

[image]

[image]

My current approach is to directly use the Beta function and set $\epsilon$ in the Beta function to 0 forcefully. However, when I calculate it, the term on the left side of the inequality tends to infinity, while the right side is $\pi$. Is there something wrong with my calculation process? If there is, could you provide a correct proof process?